# Правильный JSON

Tags: php

Есть файл с данными из которого нужно выбрать определенные данные, сформировать JSON и отправить по запросу на клиент. Пока это выглядит так

ФАЙЛ:

```
time <wbr> NaN <wbr> someData <wbr> 112 <wbr> 3 <wbr> 0 
   <wbr> -1 <wbr> someData  <wbr> someData  <wbr> 0 <wbr> 0 
   <wbr> someData  <wbr> productId_1 <wbr> productId_2
```

Это пример одной строки txt файла, таких строк много.

```
$handle = 'file.txt';
$f = fopen($handle, "r");
$full_file  = [];
$one_string = [];
$page_of_product = [];
$position_of_product = [];

while(!feof($f)) { 
    $arr[] = fgets($f); // добавляю в массив по 1 строке из файла
}
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
    $arr2[] = explode("<wbr>", $arr[$i]);// формирую массив из каждой строки (<wbr> - это просто разделитель столбцов)
}
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr2); $i++) { 
    $page_of_product[]     = [$i => $arr2[$i][4] ];
    $position_of_product[] = [$i => $arr2[$i][3] ];
}//так я получаю массивы с нужными данными (нужна ячейка 3 и 4)
```

А далее я не знаю как из этих массив сформировать корректный JSON, если писать просто `$page_of_product = json_encode($page_of_product);` то JSON получается не корректный...как правильно сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: С чего вдруг функция json_encode() возвращает некорректно сформированную строку с json данными?

Comment: Мне кажется, что сам массив я формирую коряво

Comment: Значит формируйте его правильно. Откуда нам знать, как для вас правильно сформированный массив выглядит?

Comment: Для меня правильный, тот который я смогу распарсить на клиенте) сейчас тот массив который приходит на клиент я не могу распарсить (получаю ошибку), я так понимаю ошибка в формировании массива, образец `$page_of_product` https://jsfiddle.net/jc9tmqv8/1/  и `$position_of_product` https://jsfiddle.net/zzkccm0s/

Comment: совершенно не очевидна структура входного массива и  что куда вы ходите из него взять - https://eval.in/903562

Comment: На вход я получаю только файл с текстом, вверху я скинул пример только одной строки из файла, таких строк много, но структура одинаковая https://eval.in/903581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Для меня правильный, тот который я смогу распарсить на клиенте)*

Давайте, сделаем массив объектов, типа `[{"page":" 3 ","position":" 112 "}]`

```
$handle = 'php://stdin';
$res = [];
foreach (file($handle, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) { 
    $arr2 = explode("<wbr>", $line);
    $res[] = ['page'=> $arr2[4], 'position'=> $arr2[3]];
}

echo json_encode($res);
```